# Reading File from ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, fill, file-handling

So I have a program that is attempting to read in a file to fill in an ArrayList, but keep getting this error when I run the program:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 69652E77
```

The code:

```
File saveList = new File("PlayerDatabase.dat");

if(saveList.exists())
{
    FileInputStream FileStream = new FileInputStream(saveList);
    ObjectInputStream ObjStream = new ObjectInputStream(FileStream);

    list = (List<Player>)ObjStream.readObject();
    ObjStream.close();
}
```

Comment: Your file doesn't store an ArrayList Object. It probably stores a series of strings.

Comment: ObjStream.readObject(); does not return a List<Player>. 
Edit: i see that Eliott Frisch just had same answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you construct an `ObjectInputStream`, the constructor reads the first two bytes using `readStreamHeader()` from the stream expecting them to be the magic values that should be present in an object stream.

```
protected void readStreamHeader()
        throws IOException, StreamCorruptedException
    {
        short s0 = bin.readShort();
        short s1 = bin.readShort();
        if (s0 != STREAM_MAGIC || s1 != STREAM_VERSION) {
            throw new StreamCorruptedException(
                String.format("invalid stream header: %04X%04X", s0, s1));
        }
    }
```

Thus if it doesn't find either of them it throws the `StreamCorruptedException` as is evident from the source above. make sure that the file is written in correct format.

Comment: I have one question, recently I'm working on chat application through Swing. When I connect to socket IP and pOrts through java it works but when I do telnet it wait in line 

           short s0 = bin.readShort();
It wait untill someone don't type anything in console and because of this it is not allowing my other users to login as it is in waiting state.

Is there a way to stop Telnet calls?

Answer (score 0):

It seems file has not been serialized in correct format, so StreamCorruptedException is thrown while de-serialization.